# Making normal text to standard HTML character

Tags: html

Simple HTML code is:

```
<li><a class='homex' expr:href='data:blog.homepageUrl'>Home</a></li>
```

Standard HTML characters of the above line:

```
&lt;li&gt;&lt;a class=&#39;homex&#39; expr:href=&#39;data:blog.homepageUrl&#39;&gt;Home&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
```

Is there any way to convert simple HTML to standard HTML directly?

Comment: You mean you need to HTMLEncode that string? Using what language?

Comment: I need to HTML Encode a loooot of string. Standard English?

Comment: Um, no :) sorry should've been more clear. What programming language - JavaScript, C# etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, using Notepad++, the [HTMLTag](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central#_45) plugin does what you want (my preference).

Or try these sites: [convertstring.com](http://www.convertstring.com/EncodeDecode/HtmlEncode), [string-functions.com](http://string-functions.com/htmlencode.aspx), [web2generators](http://www.web2generators.com/html/entities), search engines...

Comment: Thank you. I am exactly looking for this tool.